# add Checkbox on Action Bar Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-actionbar

I've a problem when i was adding Check box on Action Bar, it is not showing Check box on Action Bar only showing checkbox title.

`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/check_all"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.checkbox"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_check"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_add"/>
```

`
this is my menu.XML

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.checkbox"`

to `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"`

so that android can recognize the checkbox actual class name.

Comment: You mean `android.widget.CheckBox` not `android.widget.Checkbox`?

Comment: Really? Did not know since `CheckBox` is the actual class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html. If true, good to know ;)

Comment: I have updated the answer please check.Happy coding :)

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer not working for me.
`Checkable` tag did the trick:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/check_all"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_check"/>
```

And then in the Activity who inflates it you should have something like this in order to reflect the change of the checked state (otherwise it won't change the selected state even if you press it):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.check_all:
            item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to set the MenuItem checked on start, you can do in onCreateOptionsMenu: MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.check_all);
        item.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("my_prefs_key", false));