# How can I add a checkbox in my menu item in my fragment v4?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, checkbox, menu

I have a fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment. And I need a checkbox in my menu, but I know I can't use  getSupportActionBar(), so How another choice I have?
Thanks a lot.

[image: my activity looks likes this]

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918960/add-checkbox-on-action-bar-android)

Comment: Why not create the checkbox in the activity that instantiates the fragment?

Comment: Yes. That will be my last option If I can't do it in my menu. The problem is the fragment  v4 doesn't support getSupportActionBar().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `onCreateView` add this line:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

then override the following :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_frag, menu);
}
```

Comment: Yes Thanks. So How is the XML? Do I need a "android.widget.CheckBox"?

Comment: this will boil down to how to add checkbox to menu in general. if you want it to be always visible (showAsAction:always) then you need to do a bit more than just add a "android:checkable="true". you can try settings the "icon" to a drawable with "state:checked = true" then check and uncheck it on "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)"