# Adding a checkbox in conextual action bar

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to add a check box to contextual action bar.
First idea was to set android:actionLayout it worked but I cannot to get if this checkbox was clicked

```
case R.id.action_select_all:
                Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
```

Second idea was to set icon in this way

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_select_all"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="Item"
    android:icon="@drawable/check_box"
    android:checkable="true"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

icon

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck"></item>
</selector>
```

I get Toast but Icon doesn't change. How should I do it. I found that setting a actionLayout should work but I cannot get the source

EDIT:
I'am trying something like this but it also doesn't work

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_select_all"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/my_checkbox"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="Item"
    android:checkable="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

and action

```
@Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) item.getActionView();
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: [Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32702944/5288316) says you should update the item when pressed maybe it can help

Comment: I have tried this solution but it it doesn't work. In cab I get an icon of checkBox but onItemActionClicked doesn't recongise this item

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/check_all"
   android:checkable="true"
   android:showAsAction="always"
   android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" 
   android:title="@string/action_check"/>``
```

And then in the Activity who inflates it you should have something like this in order to reflect the change of the checked state (otherwise it won't change the selected state even if you press it):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  switch(item.getItemId()){
     case R.id.check_all:
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
        return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer it works but I don't have a checkbox icon, I have only title