# Java android NavigationView with checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-navigationview

I want to create a NavigationView with **checkbox** or **switch** , I just want to have this feature in my navigation to items switch and it should work just like this : When I turn one switch to another it changes to off state. What I did to have a switch is, this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/switchs"
           />
    </LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu1"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Menu 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu2"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Menu 2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu3"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_switch"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Menu 3" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu4"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_switch"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:title="Menu 4" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

But I can not have a value or status a switch and have a listener to see a change status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918960/add-checkbox-on-action-bar-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all create a layout action_view_checkbox.xml as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

and add layout as an item to the menu

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/check_box_menu"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/action_view_checkbox"
        android:title="Title" />
</menu>
```

And check click event as

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.check_box_menu);
View actionView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

  }
});
```

Comment: But how I can check if this checkbox is selected or not ?

Comment: I havent tried but try this:                                                                 ChechBox checkbox=(CheckBox) actionView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox); checkbox.setOnCheckChangeListner